# Non http pages are redirecting to home page (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

I would like all my pages for http to redirect to the same location as https

for example

http://www.domain.com/somepage/ now redirects to https://www.domain.com

I would like it to redirect to https://www.domain.com/somepage/

When I applied the rule

```
return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

EDIT:

Adding the header of file

```
#enter preformatted text here`rackspacedigital.com

    server {

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
```

Do I need to separate out the listen to two server blocks?

Answer (score 0):

set unsecure base url to `https://`
and also maybe a problem with Redirect to base url in magento  web settings, set to "no".

i hope your config looks like this?

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    domain.com;
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
add this in nginx `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";` in `\.php$` location or `http {}` block.

check headers if it works in either location 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/mhbpoeinkhpajikalhfpjjafpfgjnmgk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Where do I add  the "add_header" call?

Comment: updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

Copy file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` 

Modify method `protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)` from

```
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost() || strtolower($request->getMethod()) == 'post') {
            return;
        }

        $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
        if (!$redirectCode) {
            return;
        } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
            $redirectCode = 302;
        }

        if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
        if (!$baseUrl) {
            return;
        }

        $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
        if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
            || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
        ) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($baseUrl, $redirectCode)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

to

```
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost() || strtolower($request->getMethod()) == 'post') {
            return;
        }

        $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
        if (!$redirectCode) {
            return;
        } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
            $redirectCode = 302;
        }

        if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
        if (!$baseUrl) {
            return;
        }

        $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
        $newUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/') . $requestUri; // PD-April-170
        if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
            || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
        ) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($newUrl, $redirectCode)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Under `system->configuration->web->Url Options` , set the flag `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `Yes`.